# Looking For Live Exchange Backup Solution Utilitizing the Cloud (S3, Azure, whatever)

Tags: backup, exchange, cloud-storage, ms-sql

I have been tasked with finding some software or a service which can backup user mailboxes from a live Exchange server and SQL databases from MSSQL servers much like a Barracuda device might perform. We have looked into Amazon's S3 storage service but I am not picky. I would like to find something rather inexpensive if possible.

Have you implement such a backup strategy for Exchange/SQL?

What services/software do you know of that performs this live backup operation?

Is there a method you know of that would allow me to transfer backups of these services in a different way (offline backup or something)?

Links to products/services and any other details are greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [MozyPro](http://mozy.com/pro)
It will backup Exchange 2003,2007, and 2010 as well as all MS SQL versions.